# Minimum number of swap of operator to complement expression tree evaluation

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have an expression tree where each leaf node contains 0 or 1 as value, and all the internal nodes contain "&" or "||" as operator. Now I need to evaluate the tree; the result will be either 0 or 1.

The question is minimum number of swap of internal node required to complement the result of original expression tree. Any internal node can be flipped; e.g. if it is a "&", we can make it "||", and vice versa.

To solve this I tried the following technique but I didn't succeed in it:
My approach was that I would check the root whether it is a "&" or "||" operator and whether the result of evaluation tree 0 or 1, depending on that I went forward with the evaluation.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here; what are you struggling with, what did your attempts produce, etc?

Comment: I am asking how to solve the problem, I am struggling with implementation of tree traversal to solve that , can we solve it with any tree traversal or some other approach is required

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i understood you question. if it's how do evaluate the whole tree my answer is:

try a recursion.
something like this:

```
evalute() {
    if_the_root_is_an_operator() {
       l= evaluate(left operant) 
       r= evaluate(right operant)
       return calculate(l,r)  // depending on what operator it was
    } 
    // not an operator, so it'S a leaf
    return value;
}
```

optimizations could be, to check if l or r are values, and skip the evaluation if their values already define the final result. 
"0 AND (subtree)" is surely 0, 
"1 OR (subtree)" is 1, so subtree doesn't need to be evaluated

```
evalute() {
    if (the_root_is_an_operator()) {
       if (  operator_is_and() &&
            (left_is_leaf() && value(left)==0) || 
            (right_is_leaf() && value(right)==0)) 
          return 0;
       if (  operator_is_or() &&
            (left_is_leaf() && value(left)==1) || 
            (right_is_leaf() && value(right)==1)) 
          return 1;
       l= evaluate(left operant) 
       r= evaluate(right operant)
       return calculate(l,r)  // depending on what operator it was
    } 
    // not an operator, so it'S a leaf
    return value;
}
```

Comment: see, I know how to evaluate a expression tree, the question is minimum no of flip of operators to compliment the result of original expression tree,
if the evaluated value of the tree is 0 we need to find minimum no of flips of operator to make it 1 and vice versa, can it done by any particular tree traversal

Comment: you could completely invert the whole tree, for `!(a && b)` is `!a || !b` and `!(a || b)` is `!a && !b` . so you swap all operators ( and invert it's operants) down to the leafs. you'd then have to flip each operator in the tree once

Comment: that doesn't gives minimum

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of problem asked in question.

```
 OR
```

/    \
  OR     AND
 /  \   /   \
1    0  1    1

Output is 1.  Need to found min numbers of operands to be changed to change the output to 0.
Min number of operators required to be changed are 2.

```
class A {   

int min=Integer.max;  


int minNumber(Tree node)  {  

if(node==null) return Math.max;  

if(node.left==null && node.right==null) return Math.max; 

 String c = node.data;   
 int l = evaluate(node.left); 

 int r = evaluate(node.right);  

if(l || r==0) {     min_number = 1; }  

else {      

    if(l && r == 1 )     
    {         
    min_number = 0;     
    }     

    else if(l && r == 0)     
    {         
     min_number = 0;     
    }           

int left = min_number + minNumber(node.left)     
int right = min_number + minNumber(node.right);      
min_number = Math.min(left,right); 
}  

if(min_number<min) min = min_number;  return min;  

}
```